# Google sheet script to match and copy based from another adjacent cell

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image: This is the reference table]

I am trying to look for matching cells in column R,T,and V in the reference table with column C in the main sheet. If there is a match then copy the assigned number in Q,S, and U and past it in column B next to the its match.

I have done the example manually.

[image: The main sheet]

[image: Simpler Example]

Comment: Looks like a pure chaos disguised as an excel table...

Comment: Yes.. thats why I need help lol

Comment: Is the sheet that contains the columns `Q`, `R`, `S`, `T`, `U`, `V` from a separate tab? Also, the Column `C` on your sample is quite confusing, such as your sample for `52-5` on col `C39`, it has 9 on cell `B39` but on the column `V` for `52-05` it has an assigned number in `Q`, `S`, and `U` of `10`. Would you mind providing a simpler example?

Comment: Yes it is all on the same sheet. That should have been 10 instead of 9 my bad. I am adding a simpler example on the top.

Comment: So basically if you look at the last example I attached. Since cell F30 matches C33 then copy E30 and past it in B33 also copy E29 to A30.

Comment: Are `53-7` and `53-07` the same?

Comment: All the values will have two digits but yes it is the same. 53-07 and 53-07s is the same as will. Is if there is a way that it can find the first 4 digits it would be amazing.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If you got a worked solution it would be fair if you check it as accepted.

Comment: Yes the code works perfectly!!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

### Suggestion

Perhaps you can try this sample script:

### Script ***[UPDATED]***

```
  function findMatch() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lastRow = sh.getDataRange().getLastRow();
  var reference = [];
  var row = 1;
  var data = sh.getRange("Q1:V"+lastRow).getDisplayValues().filter(function(x) {
  return (x.join('').length !== 0);
  });

  sh.getRange("C1:C"+lastRow).getDisplayValues().forEach( x => {
    reference.push([fixForUsage(x),row]);
    row += 1;
  });
  
  reference.forEach(aisle => {
    if(aisle[0] == "" || aisle[0].toString().toLowerCase().includes("aisle"))return;
    data.forEach(match => {
      var currentData = match[1] +"-"+match[3]+"-"+match[5];
      if(currentData.includes(aisle[0])){
        //get its number
        if(match[1] == ""){
          if(match[3] == ""){
            if(match[5] == ""){
            }else{
              //if not empty
              Logger.log("Find \""+aisle[0]+"\" from sheet row#"+aisle[1]+"\nRESULT:"+"\nFound a match on these data!: "+match+"\nHeader: \'"+data[0][4]+"\'\nNumber: "+match[4]);
              pasteData(sh,aisle[1], data[0][4], match[4]);
            }
          }else{
            //if not empty
            Logger.log(+"Find \""+aisle[0]+"\" from sheet row#"+aisle[1]+"\nRESULT:"+"\nFound a match on these data!: "+match+"\nHeader: \'"+data[0][2]+"\'\nNumber: "+match[2]);
            pasteData(sh,aisle[1],data[0][2],match[2]);
          }
        }else{
          //if not empty
          Logger.log("Find \""+aisle[0]+"\" from sheet row#"+aisle[1]+"\nRESULT:"+"\nFound a match on these data!: "+match+"\nHeader: \'"+data[0][0]+"\'\nNumber: "+match[0]);
          pasteData(sh,aisle[1],data[0][0],match[0]);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

function pasteData(sh,row, colAData, colBData){
  sh.getRange("B"+row).setValue(colBData);
  sh.getRange("A"+row).setValue(colAData);
}

function fixForUsage(x){ //This is to let the code know that e.q. 53-7 is 53-07
  var part = x.toString().split("-");
  if(part.length == 2 && part[1].length == 1){
    return part[0]+"-0"+part[1];
  }else{
    return x;
  }
}
```

### Sample Sheet

- Columns `A`, `B`, `C`:

> [image]

- Columns `Q`, `R`, `S`, `T`, `U`, `V`:

> [image]

### Sample Demonstration

- After running the script from the Apps Script editor:

> [image]

- Apps Script editor log results for review:

> [image]

Comment: Awesome!! It is working but it assigns c5-1,c5-4, and c5-2 for the wrong cells. Also is there a way  the search can be done if the first 4 digits matches only?

Comment: It seems like your actual sheet has a different structure. My script adds the c5-1,c5-4, and c5-2 on the column A that is adjacent to the matched rows on column C. Will you beable to share a sample sheet that has a similar structure to your actual spreadsheet file for replication?

Comment: I change the structure to match yours. Yuri added an very simple example on top.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution (updated):

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // get all data
  var data = sh.getRange('q2:v16').getDisplayValues();
  var cols_QR = data.map(x => ({'crane': 'C5-1', 'seq': x[0], 'aisle': x[1]}));
  var cols_ST = data.map(x => ({'crane': 'C5-4', 'seq': x[2], 'aisle': x[3]}));
  var cols_UV = data.map(x => ({'crane': 'C5-2', 'seq': x[4], 'aisle': x[5]}));
  data = [...cols_QR, ...cols_ST, ...cols_UV];
  data = data.filter(x => x.aisle != '');
  data.forEach((x,i) => data[i].aisle = fix(x.aisle));                     // <--- new line

  // create the object 'aisles'
  var aisles = {}
  for (let obj of data) aisles[obj.aisle] = {'crane': obj.crane, 'seq': obj.seq}
 
  // get target range and target data
  var target_range = sh.getRange('a2:c' + sh.getLastRow());
  var target_data = target_range.getDisplayValues();

  // fill target range with info from the 'aisles' object
  for (let row in target_data) {
    try {
      let orig_key = target_data[row][2];                                  // <--- updated line
      let key = fix(orig_key);                                             // <--- new line
      target_data[row] = [ aisles[key].crane, aisles[key].seq, orig_key ]; // <--- updated line
    } catch(e) {}
  }

  // fill the target range with updated data
  target_range.setValues(target_data);
}

// function to convert  '10-1 1/4' --> '10-01', '8-0' --> '08-00', etc
function fix(key) {
  return key.split(' ')[0]
    .split('-').map(x => x.length == 1 ? '0' + x : x)
    .join('-').slice(0,5);
}
```

Initial data:

[image]

Results:

[image]

[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YnAdvB3qVpOCj3XVmX17qPiOW_Cq2wkvkN-4kRs7g-E/edit?usp=sharing)

I decided don't add in my variant the function that makes true this: `'53-7' == '53-07'` and `'11' == '11-0'`, etc, because I think it's a rather bad and error-prone idea. It will silently hide many errors in your data. But I can add it if you want.

**Update**

The function can be something like this:

```js
function fix(key) {
  return key.split(' ')[0]
    .split('-').map(x => x.length == 1 ? '0' + x : x)
    .join('-').slice(0,5);
}

// test
const keys = ['10-1 1/4', '11-0', '9-11 1/2', '8-0', '53-06', '52-7', '53-07', '104', '8-02-S', '08-01'];

keys.forEach(key => console.log(fix(key) + ' <--- ' + key));
```

I've added the function `fix()` and several lines to my original code.

But actually functions like this can cause additional troubles. For example I have no idea what means '104'? If it should be '10-04'? Or may be '01-04'? Or something else? You need be well prepared if you decide to play the risky game.

Note: you can change `orig_key` to `key` in this line:

```
target_data[row] = [ aisles[key].crane, aisles[key].seq, orig_key ];
```

This way you will get the 'fixed' values in the target table instead of original ones.

Comment: Yes please! Can you add it?

Comment: Hi, @Luke, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @luke did you try my updated code after all? Could you please provide some feedback?